# Erro no print do python

Tags: python

Olá, eu estou com um pequeno problema, creio eu que seja simples e que conseguirei ajuda aqui. Tenho um código que recebe um nome, checa se é **'elvis'**, se for printa **'bem vindo'**, se não for printa **'não permitido'**. O problema é que quando eu acerto o nome de primeira ele printa o **'bem vindo'**, mas quando erro algumas vezes e só depois acerto, ele não printa mais o **'bem vindo'**, simplesmente encerra.

```
name=str(input('Write your name: ')) #Recebe o nome

def check(name): #Função para checar se o nome é elvis
    while(name!='elvis'): #Loop que fica pedindo o nome até ser digitado o correto
        print('You are not allowed!') #Mensagem avisando que não tem permissão
        name=str(input('Write your name: ')) #Recebe o nome novamente

def sucess(name): #Função que mostra a mensagem 'bem vindo'
    if(name=='elvis'): #Verifica se o nome que foi digitado é elvis
        print('Welcome {}!'.format(name)) #Mensagem de boas vindas
    else: #Caso não seja a função acima é chamada
        check(name)

sucess(name) #Função acima
```

Comment: Editei a resposta sugerindo uma nova versão para o seu código onde as 2 funções são unidas em uma só. Dê uma conferida.

Comment: @Max Eu fiz como você sugeriu e realmente o código ficou bem mais interessante. Valeu!

Comment: Opa. Show @Uondaime Fico feliz. Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta clicando no ícone de check verde abaixo do contador de pontos. Assim você ajuda a comunidade. Abraços

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque após errar o nome, você pede para que o mesmo seja inserido novamente, porém dentro da função `check`. Assim, por mais que o nome seja inserido corretamente nessa segunda tentativa, ele está "preso" dentro da função check, e nunca vai ser passado para a função `sucess`, que é aquela que dá o **bem-vindo**.

Como você disse, era pouca coisa. Só precisava adicionar uma chamada pra função `sucess` após sair do `while` de erro de nome.

```
name=str(input('Write your name: ')) #Recebe o nome

def check(name): #Função para checar se o nome é elvis
    while(name!='elvis'): #Loop que fica pedindo o nome até ser digitado o correto
        print('You are not allowed!') #Mensagem avisando que não tem permissão
        name=str(input('Write your name: ')) #Recebe o nome novamente
    sucess(name)     #faltou chamar esta verificação aqui

def sucess(name): #Função que mostra a mensagem 'bem vindo'
    if(name=='elvis'): #Verifica se o nome que foi digitado é elvis
        print('Welcome {}!'.format(name)) #Mensagem de boas vindas
    else: #Caso não seja a função acima é chamada
        check(name)

sucess(name) #Função acima
```

Se me permite uma sugestão, acho que seu código fica mais elegante e fácil de entender se as suas 2 funções virarem uma só. Assim:

```
name=str(input('Write your name: ')) #Recebe o nome

def check(name): #Função para checar se o nome é elvis
    while(name!='elvis'): #Loop que fica pedindo o nome até ser digitado o correto
        print('You are not allowed!') #Mensagem avisando que não tem permissão
        name=str(input('Write your name: ')) #Recebe o nome novamente
    print('Welcome {}!'.format(name)) #Mensagem de boas vindas

check(name) #Função acima
```

Comment: Realmente era isso. Porém eu não sabia que podia chamar uma função acima dela no python. Eu até achei que estava faltando algo após sair do while. E obrigado pela sugestão.